# VB: Pull text from specific HTML tag into Textbox

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am trying to write a VB.Net application that needs to pull the text from a specific tag:

`<span data-reactid="85">172,890,000</span>`

and then enter the text found `172,890,000` into a textbox on the form.

In `Textbox1`, you enter the Stock Symbol you want to search.

The data for "TTM - Total Revenue" will always be held within the:

`<span data-reactid="85">172,890,000</span>` tag. Regardless of stock you check.

In `RichTextBox1`, is the downloaded source code for the url.

`TextBox2` is where it pulls "TTM". I will probably change it to a label as it's a constant value. I cant put the number in the variable as it will vary on the company, i.e. the value entered into `TextBox1`.

`TextBox3` is going to show the value I really need. The `172,890,000` held in the

`<span data-reactid="85">172,890,000</span>` tag.

I was wondering how to search for the string within `RichTextBox1`, and pull the next 7 characters after the end of the string if that would work?

My code so far is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Source As String
        Dim ttm1 As String
        Dim ttmrev As String

        Source = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + TextBox1.Text + "/financials?p=" + TextBox1.Text)
        ttm1 = <span data-reactid="65">ttm</span>
        ttmrev = <span data-reactid="85"></span>

        RichTextBox1.Text = Source


        If RichTextBox1.Find(ttm1) Then

            TextBox2.Text = "ttm".ToUpper

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual in coding, there are always many ways to accomplish the same end result. One way is to use a Regex.

For example:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Sub Main

    ' In place of a static string here, place the exact line you want to search instead.
    Dim str As String = "<span data-reactid=""85"">172,890,000</span>"

    ' Search for the match
    showMatch(str, "(\d+),?(\d+),?(\d+)")

End Sub

Sub showMatch(ByVal text As String, ByVal expr As String)
    
    ' Make sure you're expression looks the way you want it
    Debug.WriteLine("The Expression: " + expr)
    
    ' Declare the variable and do the regex match
    Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, expr)
    Dim m As Match

    ' Handle the result however you wish; for example instead of a loop, since 
    ' there should only be 1 result you could just do
    ' something like: TextBox3.Text = m.ToString()
    For Each m In mc
        Debug.WriteLine(m)
    Next m
    
End Sub
```

The above regex will find any number that matches for example:

```
172,890,000
890,000
000
2,80,000

etc.
```

Another choice might be to use a [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) control, fetch the source into it, and play around with the `innerHtml` as needed.